# Unsure of comma usage

Tags: commas

The sentence is

> Most things I’ve built and am proud of, are a result of this philosophy

Do we insert a comma after "of"? I want the sentence to be coherent.

Answer (score 5):

No comma is necessary: **"Most things I’ve built and am proud of are a result of this philosophy."**

The main subject and verb of that complete sentence are "things are". Splitting those two words into different clauses with a single comma would make the entire sentence incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

What you've got there is wrong - you could go one of three ways:

1. Most things I’ve built and am proud of are a result of this philosophy
2. Most things I’ve built, and am proud of, are a result of this philosophy
3. Most things I’ve built - and am proud of - are a result of this philosophy

Can't give you a source for this, but just seems correct to me.

Comment: could you explain your reasoning ?

Comment: We will need more of a citation than "seems correct to me" I think... :-)

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd make "am proud of" seem like a parenthetical comment, implying that you're always proud of the things you've built.

Answer (score 1):

No.

**Be proud of** is a verb itself. Just like when you don't need a comma in
 "Most things I’ve built are a result of this philosophy"

You also can use substitute verbs like: pride(v), congratulate(v), plume(v)

further reads:
[two-word verbs](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/commas/extended_rules_for_commas.html)
[comma usage](http://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/two_word_verbs.html)